# Apache rewrite URLs to lowercase if url contains catalogsearch/result/?q=SOMETHING using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

redirect htaccess uppercase to lowercase  after

http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=

From: http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=RASPBERRY

To: http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=raspberry

Answer (score 2):

That seems excessively heavy to add to .htaccess. While it's so easy and much more efficient to add it (for example in PHP) on the relevant page.

In PHP (at the top of your page):

```php
$_GET['q'] = strtolower($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: i need a condition if url contains like "catalogsearch/result/?q=SomeThing" this then i can manage rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add in the virtualhost configuration this:

```
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
```

Then, in your .htaccess add this line:

** EDITED accordng to @croises corrections **

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${tolower:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

**note:** you need to restart apache to make it work

**note2:** it will lowercase the whole URL not only that part

Comment: No, because query string is not part of the test uri in RewriteRule. You must use `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}`